# Change keyboard shortcut for autocomplete on Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

I just found out that Mac OS has a builtin autocomplete functionality that works in many places, triggered by the keyboard shortcut option-esc. However, this shortcut is very bad - I'd like to be able to change it to something else.

I'm having no luck finding this in the Keyboard settings. Is there a way to change this shortcut?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the version of macOS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to change the keyboard shortcut:

1. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
2. Click 'App Shortcuts' and press the '+' button
3. A new sheet appears. Select 'All Applications' and enter "Complete" as the Menu Title.
4. Click in the white area next to 'Keyboard Shortcut:' and press your desired keyboard shortcut.
5. Click 'Add' to confirm.

[image: TextEdit > Edit > Complete]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.
I'm pretty sure "Complete" doesn't appear in the menus, so I imagine that's why it doesn't work...

Comment: I have tried my solution with TextEdit.app on macOS 10.13 High Sierra.

Comment: Please see the added screenshot for the menu item 'Complete'.

Comment: Yes, but other applications don't have this. E.g. check Chrome's edit menu.
I'm looking for a solution that works everywhere, like the opt-esc shortcut (which does work in Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

That builtin complete functionality and the key equivalent is provided by AppKit/Cocoa. Thus you can use the DefaultKeyBinding.dict to also map that "complete:" method to something else. To remap it, edit the StandardKeyBinding.dict in AppKit framework path, to also map it to something else, add a line to your ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict that looks like this so it completes on single esc:

```
{
    "\033" = "complete:"; 
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html

and my notes and findings on
https://gist.github.com/hym3242/8e8bc10a2fed8e55973c500f1798c234

This DefaultKeyBinding.dict is very powerful and changes will be reflected in third-party apps like textareas and textfields in Chrome , with some exceptions, quirks, and features.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is the default shortcut and works fine on Mac OS Mojave.